# PHP group time events by day

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, timestamp

I have researched this topic for a few hours now, and have not been able to devise a solution that fits my problem. This answer was closest to my problem, but I do not need a total for each day. Let me explain:

I have a program I'm building in php that is a clockin system for part time employees, the biggest problem I have come across so far is the display of times at the end. I have separate tables that store the total weekly hours, and a log of each clock in or clock out. I would like to display both in one table at the end of every week.

This means I need a way of grouping all log events by day (the average is 4 per day, clock in/out before and after lunch), so I can display it all in rows. I would like the final table to have the information in this order:

Day, In(time), Out(time), In(time), Out(time), Date

The problem I have run into is when I 'GROUP BY date_updated' it automatically attempts to add all numbers together.

EDIT: Here is the `times` table (holds each action time):

```
CREATE TABLE `times` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` text,
  `status` text,
  `action_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `action_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `next` text,                  // Next status (In or Out) used for button
  `clockIn` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `clockOut` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `department` text,
  `tdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1234 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here is the `hours` table (holds daily hours):

```
CREATE TABLE `hours` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `day` text,  
  `user_id` text,  
  `calc_time` text,  
  `date_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
  `hours` float DEFAULT NULL,  
  `weekly_hours` float DEFAULT NULL,  
  `department` text,  
  `date_updated` date DEFAULT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=99 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I want to create a table that is similar to this:

[Link to a timesheet image since I can't post images (Need 10 Reputation)](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71De78qZHDL._SL1500_.jpg)

[Link to a screenshot of some example output from those tables](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p0zd8fgjyb09rdd/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-10%20at%209.15.50%20AM.png?dl=0)

Comment: fastest way for help is to include the table structure(s), some sample data, desired output. Run a `show create table tableName` and publish that along with a little data

Comment: Drew, I apologize for not responding sooner, I thought my email notifications were in order, but apparently they weren't!

Comment: just give some sample data and desired output. Trust me, it holds up an answer from someone :)

Comment: Added those two things as links. Can't post images yet. That look good? My first time! Thanks for the help!

Comment: does a day ever wrap past midnite for a shift? or don't you care if they work starting at 9pm leave 1130pm , punch in 1202am, leave 4am with those hours being across 2 days ? Also, if I were to help, the tables would be revamped. I wouldn't touch that schema with my code. I would have **one table** with info, not rollups in tables. And they would be revamped. You get your data thru reporting, not creating more tables (weekly, monthly).

Comment: there are those that would say their third shift worker "Stan" worked 8hrs on Tuesday, even though his shift started at 6:30pm. So these ideas are things to think about when you put together a good question, because they will come up, and you should know that, as a programmer, who should keep in mind the `edge conditions`

Comment: This program specifically is for part time workers working normal 8-5 shifts, there will be no multi-day clockins. I do see what you are saying about the flexibility, though, as far as necessity.

Comment: I'm willing to take any advice! I would love to learn more efficient methods for table structures and data manipulation, just doing my best to find the information how.

Comment: alright, I will be back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to get you started. FK=Foreign Key constraint. The database enforces referential integrity. A good read.

### Schema

```
create table actionCodes
(   -- Allowable action codes in system, will be enforced thru FK
    action char(5) primary key,
    description varchar(50) not null
);
insert actionCodes (action,description) values ('CI','Clock In'),('CO','Clock Out'),('Fired','Clocked Out and Fired');

-- drop table rtd;
create table rtd
(   -- Raw Time Data
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    userId int not null, -- FK to user table, not shown
    # for this example, use a char to make the code more readable
    action char(5) not null, -- code, FK to action code table, int is the way I personally would go
    actionDt datetime not null,
    CONSTRAINT fk_rtd_acodes FOREIGN KEY (action) REFERENCES actionCodes(action)
);
insert rtd (userId,action,actionDt) values (1,'CI','2015-09-02 10:23:03');
insert rtd (userId,action,actionDt) values (1,'CO','2015-09-02 12:01:03');
insert rtd (userId,action,actionDt) values (1,'CI','2015-09-02 10:03:23');
insert rtd (userId,action,actionDt) values (1,'CO','2015-09-02 10:40:00');
insert rtd (userId,action,actionDt) values (1,'CI','2015-09-02 10:50:23');
insert rtd (userId,action,actionDt) values (1,'CO','2015-09-02 16:00:03');

insert rtd (userId,action,actionDt) values (1,'XXX','2015-09-03 09:00:03'); -- bad code, error 1452
```

There is no reason to have 'next code' and time and date in different columns. And clock in and clock out in two columns if not even relevant to the code at hand. It is just a code, and a datetime. Department would never be in this table (that is awfully denormalized).

This question immediately now falls into processing with mysql variables (a mechanism almost like cursors). At least in my mind. I will have to come back to it later as they can be quite time consuming. Like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32512201/1816093) I did last nite. Each *can* have their own unique complexity, and yours has its in the form of *What If They Don't* `Clock Out`.

Perhaps someone else can pick up the ball here.

I know the tendency to want to divide and conquer, and do a rollup to another table. Trust me, we have all been there. But this data can be reported all out of one table.

The fact that you have user_id and status as text, and the columns you did, I just don't think now is the time for mysql variables. I am not saying that to be rude at all. I would hit the tutorials. StackOverflow is not that kinda site.

Comment: Great, I definitely see what you're saying about all in one table. By tutorials, were you referring to a strict MySQL tutorial?

Comment: I was meaning anything helpful in the development stack that would serve as a guided tour til you are up and running. As S.O. imo picks up after that. You are free to ask questions of course, just trying to target the best ROI for you

Comment: when I picked up `scala` (steep learning curve) a few years ago, I didn't dare go into s.o. scala tags with questions, because I knew it was not right for me. But that was my choice. Yours is not so extreme at all, you belong here, just hoping to jump start you somewhere else, first, for a few hours. Can I recommend a site, not really, they are all probably more help than harm if near the top of google results, no ?

Comment: It never really ends. You never reach some plateau, would be rather boring if you did. Just google and tinker

Comment: Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: That is not much help

Comment: Viewing the table structures and learning more about foreign keys has made a difference already. It's also good to know when I just need to go back to learning some core things like MYSQL basics and when and how to structure tables.

Comment: well I have an email address on my profile page if you want a sanity check now and then. Typing in little boxes gets weary sometimes

Comment: Sounds great! I'll be looking into MYSQL more.