# Manipulating user data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

New to MySQL and need help manipulating user data in table 1 into the structure shown in table 2.

**table 1**

[image]

**table 2**

[image]

A user session is defined as a period of user activity with requests at least every 30 minutes. A session ends when the user has been inactive for over 30 minutes.

Does anyone know how to write mysql code that transforms table 1 into 2?

The following code can be used to create the log table:

```
CREATE TABLE log
( user_id int, request_timestamp datetime);

INSERT INTO log
VALUES
(1, '2014-10-26 10:51:18'), (1, '2014-10-26 10:52:20'), (1, '2014-10-26 11:15:03'), (1, '2014-10-26 11:39:18'), (1, '2014-10-26 15:01:18'), (1, '2014-10-26 15:01:21'), (1, '2014-10-27 21:22:19'),
(2, '2014-10-15 12:19:01'), (2, '2014-10-15 12:19:12'), (2, '2014-10-15 12:19:45'), (2, '2014-10-15 12:20:03'), (2, '2014-10-17 14:55:13'), (2, '2014-10-17 14:55:19'),(2, '2014-10-17 14:55:22')
;
```

Comment: Write the code for what? You posted the insert statement. Also, are you using mysql or sqlserver? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Looks like dts86 is looking to transform 'log' into table 2

Comment: I suggest looking at creating an insert trigger on the log table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_id,
    count(*) as request_count,
    min(request_timestamp) as session_start,
    max(request_timestamp) as session_end,
    timestampdiff(
                SECOND,
                min(request_timestamp), 
                max(request_timestamp) 
            ) as session_duration 
FROM `log` 
GROUP BY user_id
```

**APPENDED**

Now with the valued answer of @drew you can get the exactly proposed table2:

Take my output table and insert his code inside the brackets.

```
SELECT user_id,
    sessionnum as `session`,
    count(*) as request_count,
    min(request_timestamp) as session_start,
    max(request_timestamp) as session_end,
    timestampdiff(
                SECOND,
                min(request_timestamp), 
                max(request_timestamp) 
            ) as session_duration 
FROM (put code of drew here) ttt
GROUP BY user_id, sessionnum
```

*However*

1. I am still thinking that you'd better set the session number in a separate field by inserting trigger fired from the table(s) with observed activity to prevent heavy load of the DB in the future when the log becomes too large.
2. Stop using reserved words and MySQL functions' names for aliases of your table (column) names (ex. `log`, `session` in your sample).

Comment: This almost works but it doesn't take this condition into account: "A user session is defined as a period of user activity with requests at least every 30 minutes. A session ends when the user has been inactive for over 30 minutes". Would you know how to have this incorporated into the code?

Comment: @dts86 I think that it is possible. However I suggest you'd better set the session number in the log table first. It seems that the log table will be filled by a trigger from other table(s) and it might become huge after some time. As soon as you plan to fill it it will not be a heavy load for the DB to set the third int field with number of the session incrementing if the prior activity of the current user have happened >30 mins before. Use `timestampdiff()` function comparing the latest input and `current_timestamp()` for this purpose.

Comment: @dts86. should you add this field you will just need to add its name to the 'GROUP BY' part of this query.

Comment: @dts86 I have appended my answer

Answer (score 1):

### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE log
( user_id int, request_timestamp datetime);

INSERT INTO log
VALUES
(1, '2014-10-26 10:51:18'), (1, '2014-10-26 10:52:20'), (1, '2014-10-26 11:15:03'), (1, '2014-10-26 11:39:18'), (1, '2014-10-26 15:01:18'), (1, '2014-10-26 15:01:21'), (1, '2014-10-27 21:22:19'),
(2, '2014-10-15 12:19:01'), (2, '2014-10-15 12:19:12'), (2, '2014-10-15 12:19:45'), (2, '2014-10-15 12:20:03'), (2, '2014-10-17 14:55:13'), (2, '2014-10-17 14:55:19'),(2, '2014-10-17 14:55:22');
```

First we will give the following a name just to visualize it:

Note below the **1800** means 30 min * 60 sec/minute

```
Specimen A
-----  
select l.user_id,l.request_timestamp,
@sessionnum := 
if((@curuser = user_id and TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(request_timestamp,@theDt))>1800),@sessionnum + 1, 
if(@curuser <> user_id,1,@sessionnum))  as sessionnum,
@curuser := user_id as v_curuser,
@theDt:=request_timestamp as v_theDt
from log l cross join
(select @curuser := '', @sessionnum := 0,@theDt:='') gibberish
order by l.user_id,l.request_timestamp
+---------+---------------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| user_id | request_timestamp   | sessionnum | v_curuser | v_theDt             |
+---------+---------------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
|       1 | 2014-10-26 10:51:18 | 1          |         1 | 2014-10-26 10:51:18 |
|       1 | 2014-10-26 10:52:20 | 1          |         1 | 2014-10-26 10:52:20 |
|       1 | 2014-10-26 11:15:03 | 1          |         1 | 2014-10-26 11:15:03 |
|       1 | 2014-10-26 11:39:18 | 1          |         1 | 2014-10-26 11:39:18 |
|       1 | 2014-10-26 15:01:18 | 2          |         1 | 2014-10-26 15:01:18 |
|       1 | 2014-10-26 15:01:21 | 2          |         1 | 2014-10-26 15:01:21 |
|       1 | 2014-10-27 21:22:19 | 3          |         1 | 2014-10-27 21:22:19 |
|       2 | 2014-10-15 12:19:01 | 1          |         2 | 2014-10-15 12:19:01 |
|       2 | 2014-10-15 12:19:12 | 1          |         2 | 2014-10-15 12:19:12 |
|       2 | 2014-10-15 12:19:45 | 1          |         2 | 2014-10-15 12:19:45 |
|       2 | 2014-10-15 12:20:03 | 1          |         2 | 2014-10-15 12:20:03 |
|       2 | 2014-10-17 14:55:13 | 2          |         2 | 2014-10-17 14:55:13 |
|       2 | 2014-10-17 14:55:19 | 2          |         2 | 2014-10-17 14:55:19 |
|       2 | 2014-10-17 14:55:22 | 2          |         2 | 2014-10-17 14:55:22 |
+---------+---------------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Then we are done if you want. But for **pretty printing**, can wrap `Specimen A` inside of another:

```
select user_id,request_timestamp,sessionnum
from
(   select l.user_id,l.request_timestamp,
    @sessionnum := 
    if((@curuser = user_id and TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(request_timestamp,@theDt))>1800),@sessionnum + 1, 
    if(@curuser <> user_id,1,@sessionnum))  as sessionnum,
    @curuser := user_id as v_curuser,
    @theDt:=request_timestamp as v_theDt
    from log l cross join
    (select @curuser := '', @sessionnum := 0,@theDt:='') gibberish
    order by l.user_id,l.request_timestamp
) SpecimenA
order by user_id,sessionnum
+---------+---------------------+------------+
| user_id | request_timestamp   | sessionnum |
+---------+---------------------+------------+
|       1 | 2014-10-26 10:51:18 | 1          |
|       1 | 2014-10-26 10:52:20 | 1          |
|       1 | 2014-10-26 11:15:03 | 1          |
|       1 | 2014-10-26 11:39:18 | 1          |
|       1 | 2014-10-26 15:01:18 | 2          |
|       1 | 2014-10-26 15:01:21 | 2          |
|       1 | 2014-10-27 21:22:19 | 3          |
|       2 | 2014-10-15 12:19:01 | 1          |
|       2 | 2014-10-15 12:19:12 | 1          |
|       2 | 2014-10-15 12:19:45 | 1          |
|       2 | 2014-10-15 12:20:03 | 1          |
|       2 | 2014-10-17 14:55:13 | 2          |
|       2 | 2014-10-17 14:55:19 | 2          |
|       2 | 2014-10-17 14:55:22 | 2          |
+---------+---------------------+------------+
14 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Note the OP's definition of a session. It is one of **inactivity**, not duration.